# Javascript if scrolling down, go to div

Tags: javascript

I would like to add to my upcoming website automated scroll,
so when you scroll down, it auto scrolls to the second div.
I've been searching a lot and couldn't find anything.

Right now I've set it up on button click.
But this is not what I want.

TL:DL;
Automated scrolling to a div when the user is scrolling down or up.

Comment: use scroll value  which is a property of an element

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$( "body,html" ).scroll(function(event) {
$(event.target).scrollTo('#myDiv');
});
```

Comment: @JeroenVelde please change '#myDiv' to your div element Id .

Comment: this code have to work , please try more  to find out how it's work for you

Comment: there is no differences scroll is for jquery which  eqaul to onscroll event . no problems .